# Invalid connection string -> PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Intento hacer una conexión a una base de datos mediante PDO, el caso es que cuando indico una ruta por ejemplo con espacios y tildes no me lo hace bien, he intentado codificar y decodificar utf8

```
try {
        $host_gd_ce="firebird:dbname=192.x.x.48:F:\BBDD\Correos electrónicos\CE_00005.fdb";

        $this->pdo_gd_ce = new \PDO($host_gd_ce, $this->gd_ce_usuario, $this->gd_ce_password);
        $this->pdo_gd_ce->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $this->conexion_gd_ce = true;

        return true;
     } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $excepcion = $e->getMessage();
        $this->escribirLog("ERROR", "Error al conectar a GD CE. Error $excepcion");
        $this->conexion_gd_ce = false;
        return false;
     }
```

Si lo intento tal cual me da fallos de string pero si por ejemplo cambio la parte de "Correos electrónicos por "Correos" me hace la conexion perfecta y me hace los selects insert perfectamente

Muchas gracias

Comment: esta ruta es de tu base de datos ? Correos electrónicos 
te recomiendo que lo trabajes asi correos_electronicos.

Comment: No puedo cambiar el nombre ya que un erp tira de esa carpeta y puede que tenga que hacer muchos cambios y/o estropearse muchas cosas si cambio la carpeta de nombre